# Why does python3 allows me not to implement abstract setter of property?

Tags: python-3.x, abstract-class

I have a class with abstract property.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Abstract(ABC):

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def pr(self):
        pass

    @pr.setter
    @abstractmethod
    def pr(self, value):
        pass
```

As far as I understand, it means that I have to implement both getter and setter.

This one raises an error as expected:

```
class Implementation1(Abstract):
    pass

i1 = Implementation1() 
# TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Implementation1 with abstract methods pr
```

I am sure that this code should raise error too, because there is no setter:

```
class Implementation2(Abstract):
    @property
        def pr(self):
            return True

i2 = Implementation2()
# !!!!!No error here!!!!!!
```

Why it is acceptable? This is not the way abstract things should work.

Comment: This is a bug in python, that was rejected as won't-fix, because the implementation of @property makes it hard to implement the desired behavior, as detailed in Christopher Krauses answer.

https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/83888

Answer (score 1):

The property decorator creates a descriptor named like your function (`pr`), allowing you to set the setter etc. via other another decorator `@pr.setter`. But since you are overwriting `pr` in your subclass, you basically remove the descriptor, along with the abstract methods. In order to make a property `pr` with an abstract getter and setter you need to do something like this:

```
@abstractmethod
def _get_pr(self):
    pass
@abstractmethod
def _set_pr(self, val):
    pass
pr = property(_get_pr, _set_pr)
```

Edit:
To see that `pr` for subclasses is in fact overwritten you can check the address for it. You can also check every member (like the `fset` with `inspect.getmembers()`).

The following function will print info about a property:

```
from inspect import getmembers

def print_info(prop):
    print('address:', hex(id(prop)))
    members = dict(getmembers(prop))
    for key in ('fget', 'fset', 'fdel'):
        print(f'{key}: {members[key]}')
    print()
```

For a simple class and subclass (that doesn't overwrite the property):

```
class Test:
    @property
    def foo(self):
        return True

class Sub(Test):
    pass

print_info(Test.foo)
print_info(Sub.foo)
```

Outputs:

```
address: 0x7f8973ec8530
fget: <function Test.foo at 0x7f8973fca830>
fset: None
fdel: None

address: 0x7f8973ec8530
fget: <function Test.foo at 0x7f8973fca830>
fset: None
fdel: None
```

You can see that the memory address for the property will remain unchanged.
However, for your Abstract and Implementation2 classes you see that the memory addresses are different, aswell as the Implementations `pr` lacking a setter:

```
print_info(Abstract.pr)
print_info(Implementation2.pr)
```

Outputs:

```
address: 0x7f8973fcc7d0
fget: <function Abstract.pr at 0x7f8974017b90>
fset: <function Abstract.pr at 0x7f8974017cb0>
fdel: None

address: 0x7f8973fcc8f0
fget: <function Implementation2.pr at 0x7f8973fca5f0>
fset: None
fdel: None
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html contains bot variants my (with @property) and your (with property()).

Comment: @AlexanderChzhen The problem of overwriting `pr` still exists though. Try a `print(Abstract.pr)` and `print(Implementation2.pr)`, they have different memory addresses. Using the `inspect.getmembers()` function on them will also tell you that `fset` for Abstract is a function, for Implementation2 it's None. So the only way (afaik) to get an error if one of the getter/setter/deletter methods is not implemented would be without the decorator. I'll edit my answer with my output of those print calls.